# Install finished, goes to reboot and gets stuck

Tags: release-loki, software-installation

I've installed the operating system and when it gets to finalising the restart, it says reboot: restarting done. It doesn't restart and has been sat there for 20+ minutes. I try to include an image but it doesn't show.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4qcH.jpg

Comment: force the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get past it. I restarted, it booted into grub and I edited the boot of elementary. I added acpi=off and the OS started to function.